# Find point of interest on image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to track little white dots on edges table. In most of case it works. I'm using cornerHarris function like it's used in this tutorial : http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/trackingmotion/harris_detector/harris_detector.html . 
Sometimes, I have got a problem : reflection of the light on edges creates point of interest which I have to not consider.
For example :
[image]
I'm searching to the two nearest points of the top corners, as you can see on the right edges, i have find dots(red and green dots) and on the left edges, light noise is a problem (cyan and blue dots).

Does someone knows a method to keep only dots white on my picture ? Thankyou and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the purely image processing part, I would recommend using some kind of **shape feature analysis**(like comparing the histogram in say 8x8 around your currently examined point of interest to precomputed ones of the features you want .

This would mean that you first look for points with Harris corners, then compare the features to dismiss unwanted ones ( euclidian distance in the 8x8 = 64D ?). This of course assumes the existence of a strong feature (read "taking time to find a good one") 
It also assumes you already *know* what your feature points look like beforehand.

Alternative more on the computer vision side : use geometry of your corner points repartition to your advantage : you probably want a distorted rectangle, so make sure you find one ! Surely you can compute a function that gives the validity of the last feature point assuming 3 others ? (Distance of intersection of the 2 lines generated by the other 3 points ...)

The typical and coolest approach would then apply RANSAC to it : try random (but not all !) combinations of your points and check which one fits best using that function, and consider those as good.

If you intend on tracking over time or over several images, you will have to tune it a bit, as ransac can occasionally fail (statistics of random combinations ...), and you would then use points from your previously successful run to guestimate the position.

Last idea for the moment : use some color-aware derivation technique : do you compute Harris corner of the rgb image or of a flattened version to gray ? Some gradients use color information as extra tip to discern edges, and I'm not sure the corners you're finding use any of those. Then again it might mean reimplementing Harris corners algorithm (try it, it's fun, and not that hard if you have a good algebra library to do the heavy work)

I recommend the geometric test of fitting as it uses wisely model-info of your system rather than assumptions on how reflections look like.

Really funny introduction  to RANSAC  : danielwedge.com/ransac/

Edit : Trusty photoshop knows what I mean : I highlighted the invalid shapes

[Valid grid, photoshop says so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJgzt.jpg)

[Invalid grid, logical, right ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKltF.jpg)

Comment: Thank you a lot for this complete answer !